# What is the best free JDBC Driver for Mc Access with Windows

Tags: java, windows, ms-access, jdbc, database-connection

I am using [UcanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) to interact with a MS Access database which is located on a network drive. I am searching the best JDBC driver for my application. Type 4 if it's possible. I can't find type 4 or 3 free.

My database performs a lot of updates, inserts and reading data activities.

Thank for your help.

Comment: looking for software, books, library or other resources in stackoverflow is considered as off toppics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UcanAccess is a driver *pure java*, so it is of type 4.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver):

> The JDBC type 4 driver, also known as the **Direct to Database Pure Java**
>   **Driver**, is a database driver implementation that converts JDBC calls
>   directly into a vendor-specific database protocol.

From [UcanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) website:

> an **open source Java JDBC Driver** implementation which allows Java
>   developers and jdbc client programs [...] Because it is **a pure java implementation** it run in both Windows and non-Windows Operative Systems